# How to put all html elements into a single msgbox

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

I am able to get to the web site and have it populate the innerText of each of the getElementsByClassName.  It cycles through each one in individual msgbox.  I would like to get it to populate all the information of each field in one msgbox if possible.

I have tried adding arrays but that did not work.

```
Dim o As Object, oColl As Object
Set oColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("ClientInfo")
For Each o In oColl
MsgBox o.innerText
  Next o
```

No error, it just cycle through each field in a separate msgbox.  I have to click through each one (40 pop up message box) individually.

Comment: Why is this tagged [access-vba]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect them in one string:

```
Dim o As Object, oColl As Object
Dim s As String

Set oColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("ClientInfo")

For Each o In oColl
    s = s & o.innerText & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox s
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome.  Thank you so much.  Now I can do the same for the other sections.